# Como pegar a informação de dentro da imagem em PHP?

Tags: php, imagem, marcadores

Estou precisando pegar as informação de dentro da imagem com o PHP, informações como: **Marcas (ou tag), Titulo, Comentários, Autores e Direitos Autorais**.

Alguém sabe como pegar essas informações usando o PHP?

Comment: Você quer disser que estão nas propriedades da imagem? ou que esta escrito na imagem?

Comment: Caro Carlos, falta algo na resposta do [@Wallace](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/128839/3635)? Ela resolveu o seu problema?

Answer (score 3):

Use a função `exif_read_data`

> A função `exif_read_data()` lê os cabeçalhos EXIF de um arquivo de imagem JPEG ou TIFF. Retorna uma matriz associativa aonde os índices são os nomes dos cabeçalhos e os valores são os valores associados a estes cabeçalhos. Se nenhum dado puder ser retornado, então o resultado é FALSE.

Para ativar ela no seu `php.ini` **remova o `;`** da linha:

- Se for PHP 7.2 (windows, mac osx, linux):

  ```
  ;extension=exif
  ```
- Se Windows e a versão for anterior ao PHP 7.2:

  ```
  ;extension=php_exif.dll
  ```
- Se Linux/Mac OSX e a versão for anterior ao PHP 7.2:

  ```
  ;extension=exif.so
  ```

Após remover o `;`, ficando apenas:

```
extension=exif
```

ou

```
extension=php_exif.dll
```

ou

```
extension=exif.so
```

Reinicie o servidor, Apache, Nginx, etc

> Note que em Windows é necessário habilitar o mbstring também, assim em PHP 7.2:
>
> ```
> extension=mbstring
> ```
>
> Em versões anteriores do PHP:
>
> ```
> extension=php_mbstring.dll
> ```

Exemplo de código de uso:

```
$exif = exif_read_data('tests/test1.jpg', 'IFD0');

$exif = exif_read_data('tests/test2.jpg', 0, true);

foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
    foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
        echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
    }
}
```

---

Note que no PHP 7.2 foi adicionado suporte ao seguintes formatos de EXIF:

- Samsung
- DJI
- Panasonic
- Sony
- Pentax
- Minolta
- Sigma/Foveon
- AGFA
- Kyocera
- Ricoh
- Epson

Referência: http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exif-read-data.php